# GenericDao on Datastax java driver 4

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is the following approach to a GenericDao  possible  with the v4 java driver? How ?

```
public static <T> List<?> retrieve(Class<?> clazz, BoundStatement boundStatement) throws Exception {

        List<?> tList = new ArrayList<>();
        Result<?> result = null;
        MappingManager manager = null;

        Session session = CassandraUtil.getSession();

        ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement);

        int totRows = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();

        if (totRows > 0) {

            manager = new MappingManager(session);
            Mapper<?> m = manager.mapper(clazz);
            result = (Result<?>) m.map(resultSet);
            tList = result.all();
        }

        return tList;
    }
```

This approach provided tremendous  productivity  by using a GenericDao  across the entire application.

I am assessing the changes to move to the V4  of the javadriver but I am hitting the wall as it seems not possible to do the same with the java driver V4.

Thanks

IPVP

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@GetEntity` annotation on DAO](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/mapper/daos/getentity/) to convert `Row` object into your POJO.  You can also convert `ResultSet` into POJO, iterable of POJOs, etc. - depending on return value of the function.  Here is example from documentation:

```java
@Dao
public interface ProductDao {
  @GetEntity
  Product asProduct(Row row);

  @GetEntity
  PagingIterable<Product> asProducts(ResultSet resultSet);

  // ...
}
```

See documentation for more details.